# Preciso de ajuda para utilizar uma lista com links em um for para abrir esses links um de cada vez e retirar algumas informacoes

Tags: python, lista, for, selenium-webdriver

Atualmente estou fazendo uma base de dados de receitas e preciso retirar nome,ingredientes e modo de preparo,mas sao muitas receitas entao estou entando automatizar uma parte do processo com o selenium.Porem nao consigo fazer um for abrindo cada link apartir de uma lista anteriormente gerada com todos esses links.O codigo esta assim:

```
lista_nome=[]
lista_ingrediente=[]
lista_modo=[]
nav=webdriver.Chrome(service = servico)
for i in range(len(recipes1)):
    nav.get(recipes1[i])
    sleep(10)
    nome = nav.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'h1')
    lista_nome.append([nome])
    print (nome.text)
    ingredientes = nav.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'ingredients-card')
    lista_ingrediente.append([ingredientes])
    print (ingredientes.text)
    modo_de_preparo = nav.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'directions-card')
    lista_modo.append([modo_de_preparo])
    print(modo_de_preparo.text)
    nav.close()
```

A recipes1 é a lista de links que eu gerei anteriormente e o sleep esta ali so pra pagina terminar de carregar antes de retirar os dados.Se eu rodo a parte que esta no for com um link so ele faz certinho,o problema esta ao pegar o link da lista e abrir a pagina com ele.

Comment: Você falou algumas vezes que tem um problema e que ocorre um problema, e inclusive quando o problema ocorre, mas qual é o tal do problema?

Comment: O `webdriver.Chrome(service = servico)` fora do `for` vai sempre reutiliza-lo, poderia  realoca dentro do `loop` ... Para esse tipo de programação o `sleep` tem significado diferente o qual não colabora muito. O `sleep` pausa o código o que pode ocorrer é que a pagina ainda esta carregando e não esta completamente feita.

Comment: O indicado é utilizar o `WebDriverWait` pq ele antes de continuar ele recebe uma condição que só vai prosseguir quando a pagina estiver  no estado completo

Comment: Já tentou retirando o `nav.close()`

Comment: Cesar o problema é a abertura dos links ja que nao esta pegando a informacao correta na lista para abrir as paginas

Comment: Cardoso vou tentar isso mas nao parece que é isso,o problema é que a pagina nao abre pois nao pega o link em recipes[i] mas se eu tento concatenar tbm nao da certo,obrigada pela indicacao vou ver se ajuda

Comment: Paulo o nav.close() ta ali pra fechar a aba depois de retirar a informacao para abrir a proxima pagina e nao ficar um monte de pagina aberta,mas vou tentar ver se esse nao é o problema